# MySQL Else If Statement not Executing

Tags: mysql, if-statement, stored-procedures

No matter what MySQL PROCEDURE I create, the 2nd ELSE IF statement returns zero results. Each Select statement when ran separately returns a result. I don't see an issue with my syntax. I apologize if it is a simple fix. Please help.

```
  DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE TEST(type VARCHAR(7), cat TINYINT)
BEGIN
    IF type = 'coffee' THEN
        Select * FROM specific_coffee WHERE id=cat;
    ELSEIF type = 'goodies' THEN
        Select * FROM non_coffee_products WHERE id=cat;
    END IF;
END $$
```

Comment: Hi! This is not reproducible, as we do not have your tables. Can you provide the table definitions, add some data to those tables, and then tell us what data you expect from running this procedure?

Comment: This is something that really should be done in application code, or even better, avoided by restructuring the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Procedure text is correct.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE specific_coffee
> SELECT 1 id, 11 val
> UNION ALL
> SELECT 2,22
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE non_coffee_products 
> SELECT 1 id, 111 val
> UNION ALL
> SELECT 2,222
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE TEST(type VARCHAR(7), cat TINYINT)
> BEGIN
>     IF type = 'coffee' THEN
>         Select * FROM specific_coffee WHERE id=cat;
>     ELSEIF type = 'goodies' THEN
>         Select * FROM non_coffee_products WHERE id=cat;
>     END IF;
> END
> ```

> ```
> CALL TEST ('coffee', 1)
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val
> -: | --:
>  1 |  11
> ```

> ```
> CALL TEST ('goodies', 2)
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val
> -: | --:
>  2 | 222
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f94696d45b16a29300743e62541f3c45)*

Check your data and parameters.

Comment: I have checked the parameters and data. I've entered in the data manually using the phpmyadmin tool for test running the procedure. The 2nd else-if statement returns nothing. If I run each select statement individually by manually typing and running them separately both select statements return results. The problem only occurs when ran in the stored procedure.

Comment: Test using CLI - check the procedure code, the result produced with different parameters... maybe it is some phpmyadmin issue?

Comment: Yes it was my parameters. The string I passed was larger than my varchar(7) parameter size. Thanks Akina.

Answer (score 0):

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE TEST(`type` VARCHAR(7), cat TINYINT)
BEGIN
    IF `type` = 'coffee' THEN
      SELECT '1';
    ELSEIF `type` = 'goodies' THEN
        SELECT '2';
    END IF;
END $$
you can Use TYPE like `type`;

Comment: This poorly formatted answer is missing its educational explanation.